# React JS: Single Page Application has missing pages when using react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have my SPA with multiple pages and I want to be able to scroll from the first page to the last continuously, but with `react-router-dom` when I click a link it shows only one page, eliminating the others - the routing works perfectly but the other pages disappear except for the one with the  active link. Am I missing something? I've read some tutorials about SPA and everything seems to be fine. I'm using `react-router-dom` v.6.9. This is my code:

Navigation:

```
<Nav className="justify-content-evenly align-items-center flex-grow-1 nav-tab">
  <Link exact to="/">Home</Link>
  <Link exact to="/aboutus">About Us</Link>
  <Link exact to="/services">Services</Link>
  <Link exact to="/offers">Packages</Link>
  <Link exact to="/contact">Contact Us</Link>
</Nav>
```

And this is inside App.js:

```
<Router>
  <Navigation />
  <Routes>
    <Route index element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/aboutus" element={<AboutUs />} />
    <Route path="/offers" element={<Offers />} />
    <Route path="/services" element={<Services />} />
    <Route path="/contact" element={<ContactUs />} />
  </Routes>
  <Footer />
</Router>
```

Comment: This is the designed and expected behavior when using `react-router`, you are simulating a ***multi-page application*** even though the entire React app is effectively still a SPA. In other words, RRD manipulates the URL in the address bar client-side and exclusively renders routed content. If you want all your content to still be a "single page app" then don't use `react-router`, or if you do then render all the content on the same route so it's all on the same "page".

Comment: @DrewReese thank you for the reply. What do you mean by "render all the content on the same route?". Is it something  like this?
<Route path="/aboutus" element={<div><Home/>
<AboutUs /></div>} />

Comment: Yes, basically that. All the components are rendered together under a single node.

Comment: @DrewReese But if they are under the same route, the routing process will still work changing from one component  to another based on the link? If they are under  the same route what should I assign to the path of the route?

Comment: If you are linking to sections in the same page then use raw anchor tags and link to a hash, or use something like [react-router-hash-link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-hash-link) to link to specific pages ***and*** specific hash ids if you are still planning on making a "multi-page" app.

Comment: @DrewReese yes, you were right! Thank you so much for the support. I've used react-router-hash-link in the navigation, assign the hash id to the parent div of every component and now it works perfectly. Please make an answer so that I can approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the designed and expected behavior when using `react-router`, you are simulating a multi-page application even though the entire React app is effectively still a SPA. In other words, RRD manipulates the URL in the address bar client-side and exclusively renders routed content.

If you want all your content to still be a "single page app" then don't use `react-router`, render all the content into a single node element and use raw anchor tags to link to specific sections, i.e. by id hash.

```
<Nav className="justify-content-evenly align-items-center flex-grow-1 nav-tab">
  <a to="/#home">Home</a>
  <a to="/#aboutus">About Us</a>
  <a to="/#services">Services</a>
  <a to="/#offers">Packages</a>
  <a to="/#contact">Contact Us</a>
</Nav>
```

```
<Navigation />
<Home />
<AboutUs />
....
<ContactUs />
```

Where each content component is assigned an `id` attribute you are wanting to link to.

```
const Home = () => (
  <div id="home">
    ....
  </div>
);
```

If the intent is to still render some content on specific "pages" as a "multi-page" app and you still want to navigate and scroll to specific pages and sections then you can use something like [`react-router-hash-link`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-hash-link) which has basic compatibility with `react-router@6`.

For example, if the "services", "offers", and "contact us" sections were all on the about page, you could do something similar to the following:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { HashLink } from 'react-router-hash-link';

...

<Nav className="justify-content-evenly align-items-center flex-grow-1 nav-tab">
  <Link to="/">Home</Link>
  <Link to="/aboutus">About Us</Link>
  <HashLink to="/aboutus#services">Services</HashLink>
  <HashLink to="/aboutus#offers">Packages</HashLink>
  <HashLink to="/aboutus#contact">Contact Us</HashLink>
</Nav>
```

```
<Router>
  <Navigation />
  <Routes>
    <Route index element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/aboutus" element={<AboutUs />} />
  </Routes>
  <Footer />
</Router>
```

```
const AboutUs = () => {
  ....

  return (
    ...

    <Offers />
    <Services />
    <ContactUs />
  );
};
```

Either of these approaches should provide a good general direction to work with.